# Can the kernel of a non square Matrix be equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an exam coming up and I'm currently struggling with this question:

Let A be a mxn Matrix and let m < n. Which one of the statements above are sufficient that the system of equations Ax = b has a solution.

One of the statements is as follows: Kernel(A)= {0}

I know that this holds true for a square nxn Matrix, but I'm not sure for a non square matrix since it will always be either overdetermined or underdetermined and thus you will always have a variable that you will be able to choose freely.

Is my thought process here correct?

Comment: So $A$ can be interpreted as a linear function from, say $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}^m$. What does it mean for its kernel to be $\{0\}$?

Comment: Hmm, ist it that after the rank–nullity theorem the dim(ker(A)) + dim(im(A)) = n and since dim(im(A)) = max(m) it implies that dim(ker(A)) is not equal to 0 since m < n?

Comment: Yes, exactly (I was just thinking that the kernel of $A$ being 0 means that the linear function is injective, which is not possible for dimensional reasons, but your reasoning with the rank-nullity theorem is also totally ok). So I don't think the question asked here is really relevant (this condition is never satisfied)

Answer (score 1):

The system has a solution if and only if the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $(A|b)$ have the same rank, so it is not true in general that you always have a solution since, for example, if you have two l.d. rows of $A$ and different values for the corresponding coordinates in the vector $b$, the system has no solution.  Note that in the case you mention, Ker$(A)$ is never $\{0\}$.